# Multiple forms in ASP.NET Core Razor Page, one in a modal

Tags: forms, modal-dialog, razor-pages

I am using the new ASP.NET Core Razor Pages.  I have a standard login form on the page; works fine.  I want to add a second form in a modal dialog on the page (forgot my password).  When the user submits the modal form, I want to manually submit the form and show a message on the modal (the user then clicks close on the modal).  Maybe I can't do a standard form, but was hoping to somehow leverage all the model binding and validation that comes in a Razor Page.

Any ideas on how to set up the form in the modal, submit the "forgot my password" request to the server, then display a message in the modal?

Comment: Not sure if there is a simple SO answer to this question. Better to ask a specific question with sample code. One thing to look at is having multiple Post handlers on the same page - see https://codingblast.com/asp-net-core-razor-pages-handlers/

Comment: I'll try to post a more specific question.  Thanks,.

Answer (score 0):

I use ajax for that case

`$.getJSON("/Contact?handler=CreateNewsLetters", {"email" :  email })
            .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {`
`let modal = $("#modalFinish");
                let paError = '<p>Done! <p>';`
`modal.find(".modal-body").html(paError);
                modal.modal("show");
            });`

> Contact.cshtml.cs

```
public ActionResult OnGetCreateNewsLetters(string email)
{ return new JsonResult(email); }
```